# Asp.net Core 2.2 app.UseHttpsRedirection() is not defined

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp-net-core-spa-services

When I try to use the app.UseHttpsRedirection() method it gives me a build error saying:

> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseHttpsRedirection' and no accessible extension method 'UseHttpsRedirection' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I have tried installing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy nuget package.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseAbp(); // Initializes ABP framework.

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseHttpMethodOverride

            app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "defaultWithArea",
                    template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did you add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;`?

Comment: Yes, the builder appears to be working fine methods like UseMvc(); are working fine

Comment: .NET Core or .NET Framework 4.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UseHttpsRedirection is an `Extension` method hidden in the 
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy` DLL. You have to add it (through NuGet or manually)

See the [accepted answer here](http://Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy) for more DLLs you may need